# I supposedly installed MySQL server but can’t seem to find it on macOS Mojave

Tags: mysql, macos-mojave

I have a new MacBook Pro, with macOS Mojave (iOS 10.14.1).

I downloaded the MySQL Community Server for the Mac, latest version (8.0.13). I opened up the installation package, clicked on it to install.

It walked me through the steps, but I expecting to interact with the configuration section, but I was not prompted for anything, and I got a message that the installation was done.

I thought that at one point, I was going to be prompted to enter root password, etc. It did not happen.

I went to the terminal, and typed mysql. Nothing happened.

Where did the server go, and how do I configure it? It's not in the applications section either (nothing that I can find).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can enter System Preferences > MySQL to start or stop mysql server.

You can run it in the terminal to enter mysql monitor.

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

root is your username, and type your password, the password was set at the installation process.

You can add it to the system path

```
cd /usr/local/mysql/bin
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Adding

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

to the file.

ESC :wq 
to quit and save it.

Now, you can just type

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

There is no GUI tool in what you downloaded,
If you want a GUI tool, just google it.

If you installed MySQL before, Configuration will skip during installation. If you forget your root password, see this [Reset MySQL Root Password](https://www.variphy.com/kb/mac-os-x-reset-mysql-root-password)

Comment: There should have been a step, during setup, that allows me to set a root password, remove default database, etc. That did not happen. That's the configuration part I said did not happen.

Comment: If you installed MySQL before, Configuration will skip during installation.